# Problemas al instalar selenium en Mac

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy intentando instalar selenium en un Mac pero me salen una errores. Estoy probando con:

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

Me salen las siguientes excepciones:

> ```
> Exception:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):    
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",line 215, in main    
>         status = self.run(options, args)    
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run    
>         prefix=options.prefix_path,
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
>         **kwargs
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
>         self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>         isolated=self.isolated,
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 377, in move_wheel_files
>         clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
>         ensure_dir(destdir)
>       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
>         os.makedirs(path)
>       File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
>         makedirs(head, mode)
>       File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
>         makedirs(head, mode)
>       File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
>         makedirs(head, mode)
>       File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
>         mkdir(name, mode)
>     OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/selenium'
> ```

Comment: Creo que lo más importante del error es esto: `makedirs mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: `, Estás usando un entorno virtual? o instalando directamente sobre el python del sistema? en cuyo caso tienes los permisos adecuados?

Answer (score 1):

**Instalacion**

Si utilizas [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (recomendado), puedes instalar selenium utilizando:

```
brew install selenium-server-standalone
```

**Ejecución**

```
updated -port port_number
```

Para ejecutar selenium:

```
selenium-server -port 4444
```

Para más opciones:

```
selenium-server -help
```

Extraída de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28640644/3613462